# has many through - get related object even if no associations exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I've got a `has_many :through` relationship set up:

```
class Dish
  has_many :dish_allergenes
  has_many :allergenes, :through => :dish_allergenes
end

class DishAllergene
  belongs_to :dish
  belongs_to :allergene
end


class Allergene
  has_many :dish_allergenes
  has_many :dishes, :through => :dish_allergenes
end
```

There is a basic set of about 10 allergenes. When adding or editing a dish, one should directly be able to adjust the allergenes. So my goal would be to include all allergenes with a dish, even if no associations exist.

I know I can call `Allergene.all` in the form, then loop them & check `if dish.allergenes.include?(allergene.id)`, but this seems wrong.

I've played around with different joins, but they only load the allergenes already associated with the dish. What is the rails approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_many :through` association is giving you a tool just for that - it is `allergen_ids` method. Theoretically it is just an array including all the ids, however it is shipped together with a setter `allergen_ids=` which takes an array and creates an association between your model and models with given ids. So all you need to do is to add the following in your form:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :allergen_ids, Allergen.all, :id, :name %>
```

Rails will render the checkboxes for all allergens and use mentioned method to decide which one is to be selected. After that it will send all of those in form of an array, which will be passed to mentioned setter.

Now, the issues. Unlike most of the attribute writers, passing array to a setter will actually invoke the database change - it is not cached until save is called and will execute regardless if validations failed or not. Naturally it is unacceptable. I usually got to make a "small" workaround (not to use term "bloody hack"). Trick is to override both ids setter and getter and creating after save hook. Since this is an often problem, I usually keep it in a separate module:

```
module ActiveRecord::DirtyIds
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def has_dirty_ids_for(*associations)
      associations.each do |association|
        define_dirty_ids(association)
      end
    end

    private

    def define_dirty_ids(association)
      name = "#{association.to_s.singularize}_ids"

      # setter will store values in an instance variable
      define_method("#{name}_with_cache=") do |value|
        value = value.select(&:present?).map(&:to_i)
        attribute_will_change!(name) if send(name).sort != value.sort
        instance_variable_set(:"@#{name}", value)
      end

      # getter will read instance variable, if it is falsy fallback for default implementation
      define_method("#{name}_with_cache") do
        instance_variable_get(:"@#{name}") || send("#{name}_without_cache")
      end

      # override default association method so it reflects cached values
      define_method("#{association}_with_cache") do
        if instance_variable_get(:"@#{name}")
          association(association).klass.where(id: send("#{name}_with_cache"))
        else
          send("#{association}_without_cache")
        end
      end

      # after save hook calls the original method
      define_method("save_#{name}") do
        return if send(name) == send("#{name}_without_cache")
        send("#{name}_without_cache=", send(name))
      end

      private "save_#{name}"
      after_save "save_#{name}"

      alias_method_chain :"#{name}=", :cache
      alias_method_chain :"#{name}", :cache
      alias_method_chain :"#{association}", :cache
    end
  end
end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveRecord::DirtyIds
end
```

Place this code in a new file in your initializers. Then in your model simply call:

```
has_dirty_ids_for :allergenes
```

And all should be cachable.

Comment: Thanks Broi, the `collection_check_boxes` was exactly what I was looking for. I didn't get the second part. When I use the function there are no issues...

Comment: The issue will be if you have a validations in your form: change the form so it is invalid and change alergens. Event hough you'll get the validation error on the form, alergens are already saved in a database.

Comment: @TheChamp - try it for a existing record. New records automatically cache everything before they are saved.

Comment: same result, using rails 4.0.2, ruby 2.1.1. Did you open an issue after finding the error?

Comment: Hmm , interesting. I am having that issue on rails 4.0.13. Note that it will only save allergens, the model will not be saved change.

Comment: Ye I got that... Really strange.